# Как сделать выборку из базы данных C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, как мне получить записи из БД без повторений? Допустим если цена и описание двух товаров совпадает, то этот товар не надо включать в коллекция.

Пока написал такой запрос:

```
    public async Task<List<Products>> GetProductsCollectionAsync(string section)
    {
        await using(var db = new TelegramShopDBContext())
        {
            return await db.Products.Where(p => p.Section == section)
                .Select(p => new Products { Id = p.Id, Category = p.Category, ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription, PhotoLink = p.PhotoLink, Price = p.Price })
                .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно, что бы все данные указанные в Select возвращались.

Структура таблицы:

```
class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Section { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductToBuyer{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PhotoLink { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int DeleteAnProduct { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Скрин из БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут всё норм данные отличатся, они добавятся в коллекцию, но если найдётся дубль описания цены и описания значит его добавлять не надо.

Надеюсь вы поняли)

Comment: `.GroupBy(x=>x.ProductDescription).Select(x=>x.First())` ?

Comment: @tym32167, а как по цене сделать? Может быть у них описание одинаковое, а цена разная. Чёт как-то бредово звучит)

Comment: а что если не хранить в БД одинаковые продукты? Смысл править выборки? Поставьте индекс на нужные вам комбинации полей в БД и все проблемы с выборками отпадут.

Comment: @tym32167 Я использую Sqlite и в нём нет перечислений. Допустим имеются товары условно "ключи windows" и у них всё одинаковое ,кроме самого ключа, и когда у меня вызывается коллекция для показа товаров юзеру эти повторения будут отображаться. Sqlite даже перечисления не поддерживает, а проект на новую БД перекидывать сомнительное удовольствие) Поэтому и придумываю костыли.

Comment: причем тут перечисления. Я про индкексы говорю https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/ `In case you want to make sure that values in one or more columns are unique like email and phone, you use the UNIQUE option in the CREATE INDEX statement. The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX creates a new unique index.`

Comment: @tym32167, вы меня немного не поняли. Смотрите допустим у меня в БД есть ключи от определённой игры, то есть описание и цена товара одинаковые, а ключ который достанется пользователю разный. Когда пользователь нажимает посмотреть товары, условно говоря набор каких-то ключей от игр, то он будет видеть столько элементов коллекции сколько есть в БД, то есть вечные дубли. Если бы было перечисление в Sqlite, я бы тупа кидал бы туда ключи, а потом оттуда их извлекал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123063/discussion-between---and-tym32167).

Comment: Тогда продукты и ключи должны быть разными таблицами. У вас в вопросе одна таблица.

Comment: `Когда пользователь нажимает посмотреть товары, условно говоря набор каких-то ключей от игр` - товар != ключ от товара

Comment: @tym32167, да вы правы спасибо)

Comment: вот [как пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AigiY.png), один товар и несколько вариантов его покупки. Товар - одна таблица, предложение к покупке - другая.

Comment: если хотите узнать больше о проектировании БД, поглядите на нормализацию и нормальные формы БД. Полезное чтиво.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Distinct в запросе: (сам не уверен конкретно для вашей задачи, но если это работает в запросе EF - было бы здорово)

```
class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        return x.Price == y.Price && x.ProductDescription == y.ProductDescription;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Product product)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(product, null)) return 0;
        int hashProductPrice = product.Price == null ? 0 : product.Price.GetHashCode();
        int hashProductProductDescription = product.ProductDescription.GetHashCode();
        return hashProductPrice ^ hashProductProductDescription;
    }
}

return await db.Products.Where(p => p.Section == section)
                .Select(p => new Products { Id = p.Id, Category = p.Category, ProductDescription = p.ProductDescription, PhotoLink = p.PhotoLink, Price = p.Price })
                .Distinct(new ProductComparer())
                .OrderBy(p => p.Price)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Если не получится в запросе - то после return Task'а уже со списком применить Distinct(new ProductComparer()) можно будет.